# Simple selection between two values, but not boolean

Tags: toggle

I'm looking for an intuitive, user-friendly way to enable users to select (and switch between) two possible values.

Normally, in a form, this would be done with radio-buttons, but I will have table with this choice in every row. Using radio buttons would make the table look very cramped.

A drop-down is also a possibility, but it means that changing selecting requires two clicks instead of one.

I thought about two toggle-buttons acting as radio-buttons (only one can be toggled at the same time), but I was wondering if anyone has any better ideas?

---

Note that the two values are not boolean. It;s not on/off, yes/no or true/false.
Think of the choices as blue/red, and no, there will not be more options in the future.

edit: My problem with radio buttons is that I do not want a table with rows like this:

```
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
O Green O Orange | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
```

Rather, I'd have something more visual showing whether *Green* or *Orange* was selected (and it should be editable).

An option with two toggle buttons would be

```
[G|o] | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
[g|O] | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
[G|o] | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
[g|O] | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
[G|o] | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
[g|O] | Some data | A lot more data on the rest of the line
```

Comment: You mean a [switch](https://creativevip.net/img/resources/large/ios7-switches-psd.png)?

Comment: @EdwinLambregts: but that shows like "on/off", which is boolean. Any connotation to true/false or on/off I want to avoid.

Comment: How is blue/red any different from on/off, yes/no, true/false? 2 choices is still a boolean, just a different appellative.

Comment: A boolean can be represented with a _checkbox_. Non-boolean (like the ubiquitous Male/Female) can not (well, you _could_ ask "Male?" with a checkbox, implying that not-male = female. But not-red is certainly not the same as green. In a database they may both be just a bit, but in my UI I see a big difference between on/off or male/female.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think radio buttons are that bad, but as an alternative you could use a slider with the labels outside it.

[image]

Comment: That may be an option... will think about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use three radio buttons (value 1, value 2, disabled). It's the least complicated solution.

If you want more separation between the enabled/disabled states, use two radio buttons and a check box

Comment: Disabled is not even an option. The problem with radio buttons is they are cloggy.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a situation where you have a trade off between UI screen real estate and clicks so you need to use your judgement.

Like you said, a combobox requires two clicks but it saves the most screen real estate.  If saving space is your top priority then a combo box is your answer.